# Sort records by substring (time) of attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

I have this active record query:

```
shop = Shop.find(12934)
```

I then go and get a collection of products from this shop like so

```
@product_templates = []

shop.products.each do |product|
  @product_templates.push(product.template)
end
```

So now I have an array of active record objects which look like this:

```
[
 #<Product::Template id: 185549, name: "1:30pm", position: 0>, 
 #<Product::Template id: 185522, name: "11:30am", position: 1>,
 #<Product::Template id: 185580, name: "7:00pm", position: 2>, 
 #<Product::Template id: 185556, name: "10:00am", position: 3>,
]
```

I want to update the `position` attribute by ordering each of these `Product::Template` by the time in the name e.g.

10:00am, 11:30am, 1:30pm, 7:00pm would be the order of the objects so the 10:00am object would get position: 0, 7:00pm would get position:3 etc.

How would I do this? Thanks for your time in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
@product_templates.sort { |t1, t2| Time.strptime(t1, "%I:%M%P") <=> Time.strptime(t2, "%I:%M%P") }.each_with_index { |template, index| product.position = index }
```

What I did there was sorting your template array first, then updating position based on array index.

Comment: Thanks man - my mind has just been fried the whole day. Changed to use `to_time` instead of `Time.strptime` but works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your way of filling `@product_templates` before sort is not a good way.

```
@product_templates =
shop.products
.map(&:template)
.sort_by{|template| template.name.to_time}
```